# Autopopulate cells in a row based on Active-x Dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Active-x Dropdown and want to autopopulate other cells in row based on this Dropdown.
I wrote the code in worksheet-change Event but when i select from this drop-down it doesn't trigger The autopopulat code for other rows. Any help would be appreciated.
*column 9 is my active-x drop-down list but when i select from the list the code for showing the next cell in my Resource(sheet) doesn't trigger.*

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")     'Source sheet
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 9 Then
       r = Application.Match(Target.Value, wsSource.Columns(8), 0)
       Target.Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Cells(r, 9)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52122547/edit) your question with the code that is not working.

Comment: sorry for that. here is the code in my worksheet_change.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value in a `Active X ComboBox` will not trigger a `Worksheet_Change`. Instead, use a `ComboBox_Change` event like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox "Please share your code next time you post. It will greatly help others help you :)"
End Sub
```

---

You may need to validate the selected value before running your code which can be done with a simple `If ComboBox1.Value = "?" Then`